# Solution for Alert button in app

Tags: mobile, buttons, notification, app, alerts

I am designing mobile app and confused as I don't know where to place the Replace Worker button. Replace worker button function as an alert to Superior that, worker is not available and need to be replace with urgency.

Considering the landing page is split into two tabs. These two tabs display different task and content. The issues is that:

1. Currently, replace worker alert designed on a card under Tab A (Default view). These has caused confusion as Superior only think it will only replace worker under Task A while actually the replacement includes worker for all task
2. If the card display on both tab, it will confused as a repetitive
3. Now I'm considering to change the card to floating button, only the problem with this, the replacement is not occurs everytime and floating button practically serve as fixed action.
4. Is it practical to have another button (Alert) beside notification icon on top?

Looking for clear UX solution on this matters.

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a header that's separate from the two tabs, and always visible at the top even if you scroll down. Put the button in there.

This way you don't need a button that floats at the bottom. I personally feel like buttons at the bottom are more often pressed on accident (by me at least), but that might vary per user.

Comment: Thank you. As i work around this is the most accurate way to place the button on top